# matplotlib: overall histogram externally for subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, visualization

I am wondering if there is a way to plot a histogram externally outside several subplots, something that looks like:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#some sample data
x = np.arange(1000)
y1 = np.random.randn(1000)
y2 = np.random.randn(1000)
y3 = np.random.randn(1000)
y4 = np.random.randn(1000)
ylist = [y1, y2, y3, y4]

fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((3, 3), (1, 0))
ax1.plot(x, y1)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((3, 3), (1, 1))
ax2.plot(x, y2)
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((3, 3), (2, 0))
ax3.plot(x, y3)
ax4 = plt.subplot2grid((3, 3), (2, 1))
ax4.plot(x, y4)
ax5 = plt.subplot2grid((3, 3), (0, 0), colspan=2)
ax5.hist(ylist)
ax6 = plt.subplot2grid((3, 3), (1, 2), rowspan=2)
ax6.hist(ylist,orientation='horizontal')

plt.show()
```

Sample

[image]

My biggest challenge is that I have subplots with 10 rows and 10 columns. If I produce the plots in the above-mentioned way, the code is gonna look crazily long and terrible. For the same sample data, currently the code to produce the subplots looks like this, which is my way to keep it simple.

```
f, axs = plt.subplots(2,2)
for i, ax in enumerate(f.axes):
    ax.plot(x, ylist[i])
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Putting so much subplot into one plot may not seem to be a good idea. As for your above code, simple loops with index will simplify your repeated code a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the code by using loops to reduce the repeated code. Something like the following should do what you:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import itertools

#some sample data
x = np.arange(1000)
y1 = np.random.randn(1000)
y2 = np.random.randn(1000)
y3 = np.random.randn(1000)
y4 = np.random.randn(1000)
ylist = [[y1, y2], [y3, y4]]

fig = plt.figure()

Row, Col = 3, 3
for i in range(1, 3):
    for j in range(0, 2):
        ax = plt.subplot2grid((Row, Col), (i, j))
        ax.plot(x, ylist[i-1][j])

flat_list = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(ylist))

ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((Row, Col), (0, 0), colspan=2)
ax2.hist(flat_list)
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((Row, Col), (1, 2), rowspan=2)
ax3.hist(flat_list, orientation='horizontal')

plt.show()
```

Since you do not provide your 10*10 plot data, you may need to adapt the code to your case a bit. But I think that should not be too difficult.